# connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream - Trying to upload django app to digitalocean

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I am trying to upload my django project to digitalocean droplet. Followed this article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04 to upload it.

After completing all the steps I am getting 502 bad gateway. Also the server is not running on SSL rather it is running on http//.

I followed every steps the article provided. Somehow there is an error called "connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream"

/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket -----

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service ----

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=sammy
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/sammy/myprojectdir
ExecStart=/home/sammy/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject -----

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/sammy/myprojectdir;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

I ran this commands but getting no error

```
sudo nginx -t && sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

So I need help on this.

Comment: Is your ubuntu username sammy? Because that's just an example in the tutorial.

Comment: i replaced that with my username & project name